# How to set OIDC provider for AWSAssumeRoleWebIdentity

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, openid-connect, amazon-iam

I am developing an android app which uses `firebase authentication` for signin and uses `AWS S3` and `dynamodb` for managing data/images. I am trying to delegate an access to AWS resource via `AWSAssumeRoleWebIdentity`.  The reason I am doing this is `AWS Sign-In UI` does not allow enough customization for UI and UI flow.  I decided to use `firebase authentication` only for sign-in and sign-up.

Please find the source code and `OIDC Provider` setting.  With them the error log is

```
No OpenIDConnect provider found in your account for https://securetoken.google.com/[project-name] (Service: AWSSecurityTokenService; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidIdentityToken; Request ID: 37607060-9e1c-11e8-8ae0-636eae27c3bf)
```

Identity Provider of `AWS IAM` has been created with the name of "securetoken.google.com/[my-project-name]/" with the Thumbprint that I created referring to [1] and OAuth 2.0 client IDs obtained in `Credentials` of `Google Cloud Service API & Services`.

The source code is shown below.

```
public void uploadImageFile() {
    CustomLog.logI("start of uploadImageFile");

    setIDToken();
}

private void setIDToken() {
    FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    // To get ID Token of the user authenticated by google authentication
    mUser.getIdToken(true)
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<GetTokenResult>() {
                public void onComplete (@NonNull Task< GetTokenResult > task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Token information is set to mIDToken of the global variable
                        mIDToken = task.getResult().getToken();
                        AsyncTaskForAssumeRole asyncTaskForAssumeRole = new AsyncTaskForAssumeRole();
                        asyncTaskForAssumeRole.execute();
                    } else {
                        CustomLog.logE(task.getException().getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
}

public class AsyncTaskForAssumeRole extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, BasicSessionCredentials> {

    protected BasicSessionCredentials doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // set credentials from AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity
            BasicSessionCredentials credentials = setAssumeRoleWithWebIdentity();
            return credentials;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            CustomLog.logE(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(BasicSessionCredentials credentials) {

        // upload file with S3 connection
        connectToS3ForUpload(credentials);

    }
}

private BasicSessionCredentials setAssumeRoleWithWebIdentity(){
    CustomLog.logD("start of setAssumeRoleWithWebIdentity");
    String ROLE_ARN = [my role arn];
    // set AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity request with created policy and token information retrieved through Google Sign in information
    AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest request = new AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityRequest()
            .withWebIdentityToken(mIDToken)
            .withRoleArn(ROLE_ARN)
            .withRoleSessionName("wifsession");

    BasicAWSCredentials basicCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials("", "");
    AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient sts = new AWSSecurityTokenServiceClient(basicCreds);
    AssumeRoleWithWebIdentityResult result = sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(request);

    Credentials stsCredentials = result.getCredentials();
    String subjectFromWIF = result.getSubjectFromWebIdentityToken();
    BasicSessionCredentials credentials = new BasicSessionCredentials(stsCredentials.getAccessKeyId(),
            stsCredentials.getSecretAccessKey(),
            stsCredentials.getSessionToken());

    return credentials;
}
```

Great thanks in advance.

[1] http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/iam/create-open-id-connect-provider.html

Comment: Have you considered using Amazon Cognito Federated Identities (Identity Pools) to federate the user from your Identity Provider into Cognito and obtain a Cognito Identity which can be used to authorize to certain AWS resources. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/open-id.html

Comment: @Karthikeyan Thanks a lot. I will let you know how it is going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using Amazon Cognito Federated Identities (Identity Pools) to federate (map) the user from your Identity Provider into Amazon Cognito and obtain a Cognito Identity Id, which can be used to authorize access to AWS resources. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/open-id.html for further details.

```
Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
logins.put("login.provider.com", token);
credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

Now, you can use the `credentialsProvider` object with an Amazon S3 client.

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(getApplicationContext(), credentialsProvider);
```

Comment: I checked the link you provided, and found out that the page includes a lot of valuable information.  Thanks again.  Let me try to do so, and if I have some question on this, I will let you know.  Hope it works. :)